Do estimated conditional modes of random effects follow a MVN in a linear mixed-effects model?
In an example provided in the tutorial GLMM worked examples, a linear mixed-effects model is fitted to the data on tundra ecosystems (from Belshe et al., 2013) with the following specification:
cmod_lmer <- lmer(GS.NEE ~ cYear + (1+cYear|Site),
                data=mc2B, REML=TRUE,
                weights=n)

A following suggestion is made later in the tutorial:

You can use qqmath() instead of dotplot() to get Q-Q plots of the conditional modes. [emphasis added]

I understand that random effects, unconditionally and conditionally (given the observed response) have multivariate normal distribution (see why random effects are assumed to follow a normal distribution, or section 3.4, pg. 173 from these slides by Dimitris Rizopoulos).
And I inferred from the above mentioned suggestion that estimated values of conditional modes (or means) of random effects in the model should follow a multivariate normal (MVN) distribution, and thus, we should check if indeed that is the case with qqmath(ranef(...)). However, in the formulation of linear mixed-effects model, it is never explicitly assumed that the conditional modes of random effects should have multivariate normal distribution, right? What is then the motivation behind using Q-Q plots of estimated values?

I think I can attempt to expand on Ben's answer.

Joint Normality of $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{b}$

In a linear mixed-effects model, the response vector $\mathbf{Y}$ and the random effects $\mathbf{b}$ are assumed to be jointly normal, conditional on the random effects covariance parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$. We can write the distribution as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\mathbf{Y} \\
\mathbf{b} 
\end{pmatrix}
\sim N\left( 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\beta} \\
\mathbf{0} 
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\sigma^2 \mathbf{W}^{-1} + \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{G}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mathbf{Z}^\top & \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{G}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \\
\mathbf{G}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mathbf{Z}^\top & \mathbf{G}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) 
\end{pmatrix}
\right)$$
where $\mathbf{X}$ is the design matrix for the fixed effects, $\mathbf{Z}$ is the design matrix for the random effects, $\mathbf{G}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is the variance-covariance matrix of the random effects, and $\sigma^2 \mathbf{W}^{-1}$ is the residual covariance matrix, where $\mathbf{W}$ can represent more complex covariance structures such as AR(1), Toeplitz, Ante-Dependence, unstructured etc. If the residuals are independent and homoscedastic, then $\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{I}$. See the following for a discussion about different covariance structures:
Beyond AR(1) as a covariance structure for mixed models with repeated measures
This joint normal distribution leads to the conditional normality of $\mathbf{b}$ given $\mathbf{Y}$, meaning that we are working with the posterior estimates of the random effects, known as the BLUPs, rather than the true random effects $\mathbf{b}$ themselves. These BLUPs are derived based on the observed data and model parameters. However, $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ itself is not a random variable, and its distribution is not assumed to be normal:
$$
\mathbf{b} | \mathbf{Y} \sim N(\hat{\mathbf{b}}, \text{Var}(\mathbf{b}|\mathbf{Y}))
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{b}}$ are the BLUPs (Best Linear Unbiased Predictors) and
$\text{Var}(\mathbf{b}|\mathbf{Y})$ is the posterior variance of the random effects given the data. The conditional mean $\hat{\mathbf{b}}$ is given by:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{b}} = \mathbf{G}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mathbf{Z}^\top \mathbf{V}^{-1} (\mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\beta})
$$
where $\mathbf{V} = \sigma^2 \mathbf{W}^{-1} + \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{G}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mathbf{Z}^\top$ is the marginal variance of $\mathbf{Y}$. This shows that the BLUPs are linear combinations of the observed response $\mathbf{Y}$, conditional on $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, which leads to the conditional normality of $\mathbf{b}$.
Thus, the normality of the BLUPs follows from the normality assumptions on the joint distribution of $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, conditional on $\boldsymbol{\theta}$.

Shrinkage and the Distribution of BLUPs:

BLUPs are shrinkage estimators, meaning that they pull the estimates of the random effects toward zero. The degree of shrinkage depends on the relative variance of the random effects (captured by $\boldsymbol{\theta}$) compared to the residual variance. If the variance of the random effects is large relative to the residual variance, the BLUPs will reflect more of the group-level variation; if small, the BLUPs will be shrunk more toward zero, reflecting the individual-level variation more.
This shrinkage can affect the empirical distribution of the BLUPs, which is why the QQ plot is useful for checking whether the estimated BLUPs still follow the normal distribution as assumed.

REML Estimation and its Effect on Random Effects:

REML (Restricted Maximum Likelihood) estimates the variance components (such as the variances of the random effects and residuals) by maximising the likelihood of the residuals after accounting for the fixed effects. These variance component estimates lead to more accurate BLUPs. BLUPs minimise the mean squared prediction error, making them optimal predictors. This justifies checking the normality of BLUPs through QQ plots.

The Role of QQ Plots in Model Diagnostics:

QQ plots serve as a diagnostic tool to visually check whether the BLUPs follow the assumed normal distribution. If they are normally distributed, the QQ plot will show points lying along a straight line. However, slight deviations from normality do not necessarily indicate serious model misspecification. These deviations could be caused by factors such as:

Shrinkage effects, especially with small sample sizes.
Over- or underestimation of variance components.
Incorrect random effects structure.

While larger deviations may suggest that some model assumptions (such as the random effects structure) need to be revisited, QQ plots should be used in conjunction with other diagnostic tools to fully assess model fit.

This is terribly arm-wavy (hopefully someone will provide a more rigorous answer ...), but perhaps:

the response variable $\mathbf y$ is assumed to be multivariate Gaussian
the conditional modes/BLUPs are the solutions of the normal equations, a set of linear equations involving the model matrices $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Z$, the observed values $\mathbf y_{\textrm obs}$ and the random effects parameters $\boldsymbol \theta$ (see eq 17 of the lmer vignette); thus they will be linear combinations of the $\mathbf y_{\textrm obs}$ values (everything else is constant, conditional on $\boldsymbol \theta$) → they'll be Gaussian. (Note that the normal equations are already incorporating the assumption that the unconditional distributions are Gaussian.)

In case it's not clear, these values are called conditional modes to emphasize that they're not the means on the data/response distribution; on the linear predictor scale, the conditional distributions are Gaussian and thus the modes and means (and medians) are the same ...
